# TimeZone and DST in Rails and PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, dst, rails-postgresql

#### Background

Article model with default `created_at` column

Rails `config.time_zone = 'Warsaw'`

I've got an article with created_at = local time 2012-08-19 00:15 (2012-08-18 22:15 in UTC).

#### Goal

To receive all articles created in 2012-08-19 (in local time).

#### My (not working properly) solution

```
Article.where(
  "date_trunc('day', created_at AT TIME ZONE '#{Time.zone.formatted_offset}')
   = '#{Date.civil(2012, 8, 19)}'"
)
```

Which generates SQL:

```
SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"
WHERE (date_trunc('day', created_at AT TIME ZONE '+01:00') = '2012-08-19')
```

And returns an empty set. But if I run the same query in psql it returns an article ... which confuses me.

#### Question

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: [This related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9571392/939860) may be of help.

Comment: This question would need the exact definition of the column `created_at` (what data type exactly?) and the exact value returned by psql (which does not show up in Rails) to be complete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Goal: To receive all articles created in 2012-08-19 (in local time).

`'+01:00'` (like you use it) is a *fixed* time offset and cannot take DST (*Daylight Saving Time*) into account. Use a time zone **name** for that (not an abbreviation). These are available in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_timezone_names;
```

For Warsaw this should be [`'Europe/Warsaw'`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cest). The system knows the bounds for DST from its stored information and applies the according time offset.

---

Also, your query can be simplified.

As `created_at` is a `timestamp [without time zone]`, the values saved reflect the local time of the server when the row was created (saved internally as UTC timestamp).

There are basically only two possibilities, depending on the time zone(s) of your client.

1. Your reading client runs with **the same** setting for [`timezone`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE) as the writing client: Just cast to date.

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM   articles
   WHERE  created_at::date = '2012-08-19';
   ```
2. Your reading client runs with **a different** setting for [`timezone`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE) than the writing client: Add `AT TIME ZONE '<tz name of *writing* client here>`'. For instance, if that was `Europe/Warsaw`, it would look like:

   ```
   ...
   WHERE (created_at AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Warsaw')::date = '2012-08-19';
   ```

The double application of `AT TIME ZONE` like you have it in your posted answer should *not* be necessary.

Note the time zone *name* instead of the abbreviation. See:

- [Time zone names with identical properties yield different result when applied to timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042506/time-zone-names-with-identical-properties-yield-different-result-when-applied-to)

If you span multiple time zones with your application ..

.. set the column default of `created_at` to `now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` - or some other time zone, the point being: use the same everywhere.

.. or, **preferably**,  switch to `timestamptz` (`timestamp with time zone`).

Comment: You've saved my day! Thanks! :) in my case I also needed ::TIMESTAMPTZ like this: `group("to_char(telemetries.interval_end::TIMESTAMPTZ AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Warsaw', 'HH24')")`

Comment: Helpful guide on how to migrate every datetime column to be timezone aware:  https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21126#issuecomment-327895275

Answer (score 1):

[Linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9571392/939860) helped. I have to run following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   articles
WHERE (created_at AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'CEST')::date = '2012-08-19';
```

> This question would need the exact definition of the column created_at (what data type exactly?)

Rails always creates created_at column as timestamp without time zone. So I have to make the first `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` to say dbms that this timestamp is at UTC, and the second one to display date at CEST zone.

Comment: This could be simplified. Consider my amended answer. I also clarified some details that were not quite correct in my first draft.