# Fetch number of records on date in PostgreSQL while considering timezones

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timestamp

Given that I have a checkins table in postgresql w/ a created_at column, how would I go about selecting all of the records that were created on a given date (2012-10-17 for example) while considering the timezone `'America/New_York'` (and taking into account daylight savings time)?

Currently I'm executing the following query in `psql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.6` but it seems to be missing some records that were added towards the end of the day.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM checkins WHERE date(created_at) = '2012-10-17';
```

Here is a listing of all of the records for the given day. The query above is returning 10 which is incorrect. I should be getting back 13.

```
  id  | waiver_id |         created_at         |         updated_at         
------+-----------+----------------------------+----------------------------
 1391 |         1 | 2012-10-18 00:42:07.308453 | 2012-10-18 00:42:07.308453
 1390 |       286 | 2012-10-18 00:38:53.102685 | 2012-10-18 00:38:53.102685
 1389 |       590 | 2012-10-18 00:38:28.811605 | 2012-10-18 00:38:28.811605
 1388 |         7 | 2012-10-17 22:29:25.610774 | 2012-10-17 22:29:25.610774
 1387 |      1155 | 2012-10-17 22:01:40.647219 | 2012-10-17 22:01:40.647219
 1386 |      1154 | 2012-10-17 22:00:05.477698 | 2012-10-17 22:00:05.477698
 1385 |      1153 | 2012-10-17 21:57:59.698076 | 2012-10-17 21:57:59.698076
 1384 |      1152 | 2012-10-17 21:08:32.533203 | 2012-10-17 21:08:32.533203
 1383 |      1151 | 2012-10-17 21:07:42.500036 | 2012-10-17 21:07:42.500036
 1382 |       115 | 2012-10-17 21:04:03.075333 | 2012-10-17 21:04:03.075333
 1381 |         3 | 2012-10-17 20:30:13.741647 | 2012-10-17 20:30:13.741647
 1380 |       245 | 2012-10-17 20:29:53.808852 | 2012-10-17 20:29:53.808852
 1379 |      1150 | 2012-10-17 20:27:30.057269 | 2012-10-17 20:27:30.057269
```

checkins columns & data_types

```
 column_name |          data_type          
-------------+-----------------------------
 updated_at  | timestamp without time zone
 created_at  | timestamp without time zone
 waiver_id   | integer
 id          | integer
```

Answer (score 5):

Depending what you want exactly, the [**`AT TIME ZONE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) construct can help.

If your column is of type [`timestamp [without time zone]`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) and your local time is set to a different time zone than EST, but you want the according dates at EST, this would be your query:

```
SELECT count(*) AS ct
FROM   checkins
WHERE  (created_at AT TIME ZONE 'EST')::date = '2012-10-16';
```

Can't say for sure, your question is missing basic information and leaves room for interpretation.
Comprehensive explanation of PostgreSQL's time zone handling with examples and links at [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170).

If you want **daylight saving time** covered automatically, use a **time zone name** instead of a time zone abbreviation. Like:

```
created_at AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'
```

More info about that in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042506/time-zone-names-with-identical-properties-yield-different-result-when-applied-to).

Comment: I've tried this but I still get back 10 results instead of 13. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, what basic information is my question missing? I can provide you w/ whatever you need

Comment: @KyleDecot: The following would help: *exact* data type of `created_at`; "while considering the time zone" does not clarify to which time zone the date should be applicable; your local time zone (time zone name) where you execute the query; the current time zone where you display the example data (is the same?); do you want to consider DST? Your version of PostgreSQL.

Comment: I just noticed something odd. If I do `SELECT count(*) AS ct
FROM   checkins
WHERE  (created_at AT TIME ZONE 'GMT')::date = '2012-10-17';` I get back 13 which is the correct number. That seems weird to me. Am I just confused as to how time zones work in postgres?

Comment: @KyleDecot: What do you get when you run `SHOW timezone`? And what is the time zone your database *server* is configured to? (The server setting is used when running with `localtime`.)