# Accounting for DST in Postgres, when selecting scheduled items

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, timezone, dst

I have a **Postgres** table of **clock alarms** (not really, but this is analogous, and easier to explain). Alarms are set by users with a 1 hour resolution, and users can be from many different timezones. The alarms are repeating daily. I want to reliably fetch the alarms that are supposed to go off at a particular hour of the day, and I am **having problems with daylight saving time**. How do I do this in the best way?

#### Example

> Alfred and Lotta both live in Stockholm (+1 hour from UTC, but +2h
> when it's DST).
>  Sharon lives in Singapore (+8 hours from UTC, no
> DST)
>
> During winter, Alfred sets an alarm for 4 AM. The alarm should go off
> at 4 AM local time, all year.
>  During summer, Lotta sets an alarm
> for 5 AM. Again, it should go off at 5 AM all year round.
> Meanwhile, Sharon has set an alarm for 11 AM.
>
> All of these can be stored in the database as 03:00 UTC.
>
> If I query the database in the winter for alarms that should go off at
> 03:00 UTC, I want Alfred's and Sharon's alarms. Singapore is now +7h
> from Sweden, so 11 AM in Singapore is 4 AM in Sweden. Lotta's alarm
> should not go off for another hour.
>
> Conversely, if I query the database in the summer for alarms that
> should go off at 03:00 UTC, I want Lotta's and Sharon's alarms.
> Singapore is +6h from Sweden now, so 11 AM in Singapore is 5 AM in
> Sweden now. Sven's alarm went off an hour ago.

**How do I store this, and query the database?**

I can change the db schema if necessary. At the moment, we don't adjust for DST at all, and in fact just have an "hour" integer field (which seems dumb, a time field would be better).

It seems I need to store both a UTC time and timezone information, but I don't know how to best achieve this in Postgres. I've found that Postgres has some sort of concept of timezones, but no timezone field type as far as I can tell. Also, I guess I need to do some calculations in SQL to determine how to offset the UTC time in the select, based on the timezone data and the creation date. I'm not great with SQL…

I do want to solve this in Postgres, as there can be a lot of "alarms", and I want to avoid the performance issues that come with fetching all of them into Ruby and filter there. (Yes, this is a Rails app.)

Comment: Postgres has powerful temporal types. Have you tried to use them and if yes - where they have failed?

Comment: I've tried a few things with the `time with time zone` field type. 1) I need to store the timezone to use with it as well. Can Postgres facilitate this somehow, or do I store it as a string? And 2) I haven't found how to extract DST information even when I have a timezone. My thinking: I extract hour from the time field, and add/subtract 1h if I need to compensate for dst based on creation date... but everything I come up with is so complicated that my experience tells me I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @MartinSvalin Dates and times *are* painful and complicated, sadly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `timestamp with time zone` (`timestamptz`) for calculations.
Times for alarms can be `time [without time zone]`.
But you have to save the **time zone** explicitly for every row.

**Never** use `time with time zone` (`timetz`) It's a logically broken type, its use is discouraged by PostgreSQL. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html)

> The type `time with time zone` is defined by the SQL standard, but the
> definition exhibits properties which lead to questionable usefulness.
> In most cases, a combination of `date`, `time`, `timestamp without timezone`, and `timestamp with time zone` should provide a complete
> range of date/time functionality required by any application.

Demo setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE alarm(name text, t time, tz text);
INSERT INTO alarm VALUES
  ('Alfred', '04:00', 'Europe/Stockholm') -- Alfred sets an alarm for 4 AM.
, ('Lotta',  '05:00', 'Europe/Stockholm') -- Lotta sets an alarm for 5 AM. 
, ('Sharon', '11:00', 'Asia/Singapore');  -- Sharon has set an alarm for 11 AM.
```

It has to be time zone *names* (not abbreviations) to account for DST. Related:

- [Time zone names with identical properties yield different result when applied to timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042506/time-zone-names-with-identical-properties-yield-different-result-when-applied-to)

Get matching alarms for "today":

```
SELECT *
FROM   alarm
WHERE  (('2012-07-01'::date + t) AT TIME ZONE tz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::time
       = '03:00'::time
```

- `('2012-7-1'::date + t)` ... assemble `timestamp [without time zone]`
  Could also just be **`now()::date + t`** for "today".
- [`AT WITH TIME ZONE tz`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) ... place timestamp at the saved time zone, resulting in `timestamptz`.
- `AT WITH TIME ZONE 'UTC'` ...  get according UTC `timestamp`
- `::time` ... simplest way to extract the time component.

Here you can look up [time zone names](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-timezone-names.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM   pg_timezone_names
WHERE  name ~~* '%sing%'
LIMIT  10;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2ba7e38368e43f700d4833c74321e42e)* - demonstrating summer / winter
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c03da/1)</sub>

Comment: Thanks! I will use this approach. :)

Comment: This approach requires a full table scan. Is there an alternative that would allow you to index something so you can efficiently pull out the people you need to notify every hour?

Comment: @BenDowling That's hard to achieve as the currently effective absolute time for each row depends on the saved time zone `tz`, and its current set of rules (DST etc.). Indexes can only be build on `IMMUTABLE` data. A workaround could be to have an index on `(tz, time)` (or partial indexes per `tz`), calculate the effective current `time` for every involved `tz` and filter for the pair `(tz, time)`, maybe in a lateral subquery ... The overhead only pays for big tables.

Answer (score 7):

You would do it by using a full time zone name, e.g. America/New_York rather than EDT/EST, and storing the hour in that time zone not UTC. You can then remain blissfully ignorant of the offset changes for daylight savings.

Something like the following should work:

```
-- CREATE TABLE time_test (
--   user_to_alert CHARACTER VARYING (30),
--   alarm_hour TIME,
--   user_timezone CHARACTER VARYING (30)
-- );

SELECT user_to_alert, 
  CASE
    WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CURRENT_TIME AT TIME ZONE user_timezone) = EXTRACT(HOUR FROM alarm_hour) THEN TRUE
  ELSE FALSE
END AS raise_alarm
FROM time_test;
```

Or:

```
SELECT user_to_alert
FROM time_test
WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CURRENT_TIME AT TIME ZONE user_timezone) = EXTRACT(HOUR FROM alarm_hour);
```

Comment: Much more elegant than what I came up with on my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
SET timezone = 'UTC';

CREATE TABLE tzdemo (
    username text not null,
    alarm_time_utc time not null,
    alarm_tz_abbrev text not null,
    alarm_tz text not null
);

INSERT INTO tzdemo (username, alarm_time_utc, alarm_tz_abbrev, alarm_tz) VALUES
('Alfred', TIME '04:00' AT TIME ZONE '+01:00', 'CET', 'Europe/Stockholm'),
('Lotta', TIME '05:00' AT TIME ZONE '+02:00', 'CEST', 'Europe/Stockholm'),
('Sharon', TIME '11:00' AT TIME ZONE '+08:00', 'SGT', 'Singapore');
```

Try:

```
SELECT username 
FROM tzdemo 
WHERE alarm_time_utc AT TIME ZONE alarm_tz_abbrev = TIME '03:00' AT TIME ZONE alarm_tz;
```

Result:

```
 username 
----------
 Alfred
 Sharon
(2 rows)
```

Principle:

- Store the timezone offset the alarm was created in including whether it was or was not DST at the time
- Also store the clock time converted to UTC
- When querying, use the fact that full timezone names follow the current UTC rules for times to produce a time that's in the *current* time zone for the region. Compare to the stored timestamp in what the time zone was when that alarm was created.

This also allows you to cope with cases where the user changes location, and therefore changes timezone.

This approach can be extended by date-qualifying the timestamps when you want to do predictive querying, like "at what local time will alarm  sound in  location".

I'm not completely confident in this solution and would recommend careful testing.