# Store the day of the week and time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, database-design

I have a two-part question about storing days of the week and time in a database. I'm using Rails 4.0, Ruby 2.0.0, and Postgres.

I have certain events, and those events have a schedule. For the event "Skydiving", for example, I might have Tuesday and Wednesday and 3 pm.

1. Is there a way for me to store the record for Tuesday and Wednesday in one row or should I have two records?
2. What is the best way to store the day and time? Is there a way to store day of week and time (not datetime) or should these be separate columns? If they should be separate, how would I store the day of the week? I was thinking of storing them as integer values, 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, since that's how the `wday` method for the Time class does it.

Any suggestions would be super helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there a way for me to store the the record for Tuesday and
> Wednesday in one row or do should I have two records?

There are several ways to store multiple time ranges in a single row. @bma already provided a couple of them. That might be useful to save disk space with very simple time patterns. The clean, flexible and "normalized" approach is to store **one row per time range**.

> What is the best way to store the day and time?

Use a **`timestamp`** (or `timestamptz` if multiple time zones may be involved). Pick an **arbitrary "staging" week** and just ignore the date part while using the day and time aspect of the `timestamp`. Simplest and fastest in my experience, and all date and time related sanity-checks are built-in automatically. I use a range starting with `1996-01-01 00:00` for several similar applications for two reasons:

- The first 7 days of the week coincide with the day of the month (for `sun = 7`).
- It's the most recent leap year (providing Feb. 29 for yearly patterns) at the same time.

### Range type

Since you are actually dealing with time *ranges* (not just "day and time") I suggest to use the [built-in range type **`tsrange`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) (or `tstzrange`). A major advantage: you can use the arsenal of built-in [**Range Functions and Operators**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html). Requires Postgres **9.2 or later**.

For instance, you can have an **exclusion constraint** building on that (implemented internally by way of a fully functional GiST index that may provide additional benefit), to rule out overlapping time ranges. Consider this related answer for details:

- [Preventing adjacent/overlapping entries with EXCLUDE in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504727/preventing-adjacent-overlapping-entries-with-exclude-in-postgresql/19505869#19505869)

For this particular exclusion constraint (no overlapping ranges *per event*), you need to include the integer column `event_id` in the constraint, so you need to install the additional module [btree_gist](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html). Install once per database with:

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;  -- once per db
```

Or you can have one simple **`CHECK` constraint** to restrict the allowed time period using the "range is contained by" operator `<@`.

Could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE event (event_id serial PRIMARY KEY, ...);

CREATE TABLE schedule (
   event_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES event(event_id)
                    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
 , t_range  tsrange
 , PRIMARY KEY (event_id, t_range)
 , CHECK (t_range <@ '[1996-01-01 00:00, 1996-01-09 00:00)')  -- restrict period
 , EXCLUDE USING gist (event_id WITH =, t_range WITH &&)      -- disallow overlap
);
```

For a weekly schedule use the first seven days, Mon-Sun, or whatever suits you. Monthly or yearly schedules in a similar fashion.

### How to extract day of week, time, etc?

[@CDub provided a module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19895268/939860) to deal with it on the Ruby end. I can't comment on that, but you can do everything in Postgres as well, with impeccable performance.

```
SELECT ts::time AS t_time           -- get the time (practically no cost)
SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM ts) AS dow  -- get day of week (very cheap)
```

Or in similar fashion for range types:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM lower(t_range)) AS dow_from  -- day of week lower bound
     , EXTRACT(DOW FROM upper(t_range)) AS dow_to    -- same for upper
     , lower(t_range)::time AS time_from             -- start time
     , upper(t_range)::time AS time_to               -- end time
FROM   schedule;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1a546758fbf728eae0905019c8cc2f48)*
<sub>Old [sqliddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/47d8b/2)</sub>

`ISODOW` instead of `DOW` for [`EXTRACT()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) returns `7` instead of `0` for sundays. There is a long list of what you can extract.

This related answer demonstrates how to use range type operator to compute a total duration for time ranges (last chapter):

- [Calculate working hours between 2 dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839319/calculate-working-hours-between-2-dates-in-postgresql/17282639#17282639)

Answer (score 3):

Check out the ice_cube gem ([link](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube)).

It can create a schedule object for you which you can persist to your database. You need not create two separate records. For the second part, you can create schedule based on any rule and you need not worry on how that will be saved in the database. You can use the methods provided by the gem to get whatever information you want from the persisted schedule object.

Answer (score 3):

Depending how complex your scheduling needs are, you might want to have a look at [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545), the [iCalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) scheduling data format, for ideas on how to store the data.

If you needs are pretty simple, than that is probably overkill. Postgresql has many [functions to convert date and time](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) to whatever format you need.

For a simple way to store relative dates and times, you could store the day of week as an integer as you suggested, and the time as a `TIME` datatype. If you can have multiple days of the week that are valid, you might want to use an ARRAY.

Eg.

- ARRAY[2,3]::INTEGER[] = Tues, Wed as Day of Week
- '15:00:00'::TIME = 3pm

[EDIT: Add some simple examples]

```
/* Custom the time and timetz range types */
CREATE TYPE timerange AS RANGE (subtype = time);

--drop table if exists schedule;
create table schedule (
    event_id    integer not null, /* should be an FK to "events" table */
    day_of_week integer[],
    time_of_day time,
    time_range  timerange,
    recurring   text CHECK (recurring IN ('DAILY','WEEKLY','MONTHLY','YEARLY'))
);

insert into schedule (event_id, day_of_week, time_of_day, time_range, recurring)
values
(1, ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5]::INTEGER[], '15:00:00'::TIME, NULL, 'WEEKLY'),
(2, ARRAY[6,0]::INTEGER[], NULL, '(08:00:00,17:00:00]'::timerange, 'WEEKLY');

select * from schedule;

 event_id | day_of_week | time_of_day |     time_range      | recurring 
----------+-------------+-------------+---------------------+-----------
        1 | {1,2,3,4,5} | 15:00:00    |                     | WEEKLY
        2 | {6,0}       |             | (08:00:00,17:00:00] | WEEKLY
```

The first entry could be read as: the event is valid at 3pm Mon - Fri, with this schedule occurring every week.
The second entry could be read as: the event is valid Saturday and Sunday between 8am and 5pm, occurring every week.

The custom range type "timerange" is used to denote the lower and upper boundaries of your time range.
The '(' means "inclusive", and the trailing ']' means "exclusive", or in other words "greater than or equal to 8am and less than 5pm".

Comment: I didn't think you could store arrays in postgres?

Comment: Eh? Of course. There are a multitude of datatypes (including custom ones) that you can use, including HSTORE (key-value), JSON, ARRAYs of multiple datatype, multi-dimensional arrays, etc. More details at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype.html

Comment: ok thanks a lot - the only think I'm trying to figure out is how to create a rails migration that makes the datatype of of day_of_week an integer array with fixed values 0..6?

Comment: "fixed" like ENUM types? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-enum.html

Comment: yeah only values 0..6 - I see how to do this in postgres just not using a rails migration

Comment: Sorry, can't help at all with the Rails part.

Comment: @bsiddiqui: Note that `timetz` is supported since it is mentioned in the SQL standard, but that type is broken by design for use with DST and its use is officially discouraged. [More here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649372/insert-time-with-timezone-daylight-savings/19649663#19649663). +1 on the range type, though.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks for the clarification on `timetz`, I wasn't aware that it was broken.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just store the datestamp then use the built in functionality for `Date` to get the day of the week?

```
2.0.0p247 :139 > Date.today
 => Sun, 10 Nov 2013 
2.0.0p247 :140 > Date.today.strftime("%A")
 => "Sunday"
```

`strftime` sounds like it can do everything for you.  [Here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime) are the specific docs for it.

Specifically for what you're talking about, it sounds like you'd need an `Event` table that `has_many :schedules`, where a `Schedule` would have a `start_date` timestamp...

Comment: because these are recurring events so they are associated with a specific date

Comment: Yeah, I updated my answer.  You'd "have many" schedules for an event, right?

Comment: Ok so then if I wanted to lookup up events that occur Monday-Friday, is there a way for me to do a query on start_date to find that out?

Comment: You'd find all `Schedule` objects between the dates in question, then return unique `Event` IDs

Comment: If I have a schedule with a start_date of 1/1/13 (Tuesday) and I am asked for events with a schedule from 1/6/13 (Sunday) to 1/9/13 (Wednesday) and just do a query to see what schedule objects are between the dates, it will not return the 1/1/13 object even though it should because Tuesday is between Sunday and Wednesday.