# Index to query sorted values in keyed time range

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-design, postgresql-performance

Suppose I have key/value/timerange tuples, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE historical_values(
  key TEXT,
  value NUMERIC,
  from_time TIMESTAMPTZ,
  to_time TIMESTAMPTZ
)
```

and would like to be able to efficiently query values (sorted descending) for a specific key and time, e.g.:

```
SELECT value
FROM historical_values
WHERE
  key = [KEY]
  AND from_time <= [TIME]
  AND to_time >= [TIME]
ORDER BY value DESC
```

What kind of index/types should I use to get the best lookup performance? I suspect my solution will involve a `tstzrange` and a `gist` index, but I'm 
not sure how to make that play well with the key matching and value ordering requirements.

**Edit:** Here's some more information about usage.

- Ideally uses features available in Postgres v9.6.
- Relation will contain approx. 1k keys and 5m values per key. Values are large integers (up to 32 bytes), mostly unique. Time ranges between few hours to a couple years. Time horizon is 5 years. No `NULL` values allowed, but some time ranges are open-ended (could either use `NULL` or a time far into the future for `to_time`).
- The primary key is the key and time range (as there is only one historical value for a time range, per key).
- Common operations are a) updating `to_time` to "close" a historical value, and b) inserting a new value with `from_time = NOW`.
- All values may be queried. Partitioning is an option.

Comment: Postgres version? Cardinality? Rough value frequencies? (How many dist. keys, how many values per key?) Typical time range in query (compared to total time range)? Consider instructions in the [tag info of \[postgresql-performance\]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info). What's the PK? Are there NULL values?

Comment: Yeah, of course. Using Postgres v9.6. Approx 1k keys. Approx. 5m values per key. Values are large integers, mostly unique. Time ranges between few hours to a couple years.

Comment: Please [edit] the question: All defining info should be in the question. "large integers" - any reason the data type cannot be `integer`  (or `bigint`), would be more efficient. Can the key column be replaced with an integer FK column referencing a table `history_keys`? (Again, more efficient.) What about `NOT NULL` constraints / NULL values? Is the table read-only? Or only later timestamps are added? Are old rows read-only? Is partitioning an option? Is upgrading to pg 10 (or pg 11, currently beta) an option? Any large range of values that are never queried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### DB design

For a big table like that ("1k keys and 5m values per key") I would suggest to optimize storage like:

```
CREATE TABLE hist_keys (
   key_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 , key text NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE hist_values (
   hist_value_id bigserial PRIMARY KEY  -- optional, see below!
 , key_id        int NOT NULL REFERENCES hist_keys
 , value         numeric
 , from_time     timestamptz NOT NULL
 , to_time       timestamptz NOT NULL
 , CONSTRAINT range_valid CHECK (from_time <= to_time)  -- or < ?
);
```

Also helps index performance.

And consider **partitioning**. List-partitioning on `key_id`. Maybe even add sub-partitioning on (range partitioning this time) on `from_time`. [Read the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE)

With one partition per `key_id`, (and [constraint exclusion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-CONSTRAINT-EXCLUSION) enabled!) Postgres would only look at the small partition (and index) for the given key, instead of the whole big table. Major win.

But I would strongly suggest to upgrade to at least **Postgres 10** first, which added ["declarative partitioning"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARTITION). Makes managing partition a lot easier.

Better yet, skip forward to **Postgres 11** (currently beta), which adds major improvements for partitioning (incl. performance improvements). Most notably, for your goal *to get the best lookup performance*, quoting the [chapter on partitioning in release notes for Postgres 11 (currently beta)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/release-11.html#id-1.11.6.5.5.3.2):

> - Allow faster partition elimination during query processing (Amit Langote, David Rowley, Dilip Kumar)
>
>   This speeds access to partitioned tables with many partitions.
> - Allow partition elimination during query execution (David Rowley, Beena Emerson)
>
>   Previously partition elimination could only happen at planning time,
>     meaning many joins and prepared queries could not use partition elimination.

#### Index

From the perspective of the `value` column, the small subset of selected rows is arbitrary for every new query. I don't expect you'll find a useful way to support `ORDER BY value DESC` with an index. I'd concentrate on the other columns. *Maybe* add `value` as last column to each index if you can get index-only scans out of it (possible for btree and GiST).

**Without partitioning:**

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX hist_btree_idx ON hist_values (key_id, from_time, to_time DESC);
```

`UNIQUE` is optional, but see below.
Note the importance of opposing sort orders for `from_time` and `to_time`. See (closely related!):

- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns/39599#39599)

This is almost the same index as the one implementing your PK on `(key_id, from_time, to_time)`. Unfortunately, we cannot use it as PK index. [Quoting the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html)

> Also, it must be a b-tree index with default sort ordering.

So I added a `bigserial` as surrogate primary key in my suggested table design above and `NOT NULL` constraints plus the `UNIQUE` index to enforce your uniqueness rule.

In Postgres 10 or later consider an `IDENTITY` column instead:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)

You might even do with PK constraint in this exceptional case to avoid duplicating the index and keep the table at minimum size. Depends on the complete situation. You may need it for FK constraints or similar. See:

- [How does PostgreSQL enforce the UNIQUE constraint / what type of index does it use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066972/how-does-postgresql-enforce-the-unique-constraint-what-type-of-index-does-it-u/9067108#9067108)

A **GiST index** like you already suspected may be even faster. I suggest to keep your original `timestamptz` columns in the table (16 bytes instead of 32 bytes for a `tstzrange`) and add `key_id` after installing the additional module `btree_gist`:

```
CREATE INDEX hist_gist_idx ON hist_values
USING GiST (key_id, tstzrange(from_time, to_time, '[]'));
```

The expression `tstzrange(from_time, to_time, '[]')` constructs a range ***including*** upper and lower bound. [Read the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT)

Your query needs to match the index:

```
SELECT value
FROM   hist_values
WHERE  key = [KEY]
AND    tstzrange(from_time, to_time, '[]') @>  tstzrange([TIME_FROM], [TIME_TO], '[]') 
ORDER  BY value DESC;
```

It's equivalent to your original.
[**`@>`** being the range contains operator.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE)

**With list-partitioning on `key_id`**

With a ***separate table for each `key_id`***, we can omit `key_id` from the index, improving size and performance - especially for the GiST index - for which we then also don't need the additional module `btree_gist`. Results in ~ 1000 partitions and the corresponding indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX hist999_gist_idx ON hist_values USING GiST (tstzrange(from_time, to_time, '[]'));
```

Related:

- [Store the day of the week and time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895140/store-the-day-of-the-week-and-time/19897592#19897592)

Comment: Note: `from_time timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT '-infinity'` (similar for to_time) will simply any comparisons on the interval.

Comment: @joop: Yes, that would avoid surprises with NULL values.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thank you for the extensive answer. On the point of the DB design, I did mean PK on (key, from_time, to_time), i.e., one historical value for any time slot, per key. Sorry for not making that clearer. Apart from that, the approach seams very neat. I'm curious about a) what specifically makes PG 10 faster on partitioning and what factor improvement might I be looking at?, b) similarly, if I go with list-partitioning on key, what kind performance improvement might that entail?. Thanks!

Comment: @Benjamin: I removed the outdated bit about the PK and added a lot more above, incl. why I expect partitioning to help performance. Can't give you exact numbers, you'll have to test. But I'd expect a massive improvement.