# Store previous many-to-many relationships

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, entity-relationship

I'm in the midst of learning SQL and have a question regarding storing previous many-to-many relations.

I have a student entity and a tutor entity that are coupled together with a associative table. If a student were to switch tutors, I want to store the previous tutors of the student.

My current solution is with another associative table, however I'm wondering if there are better solutions to this problem?
[image]

Comment: It depends. Another option may be to introduce validity intervals (fields `valid_from_dt` and `valid_to_dt`) and just add new row with new validity interval. It should show a good performance for current state if you set upper bound of current record to some "infinity" like `date '9999-12-31'` and partition by that date. Also it is quite handy for queries on historic data as you just need to put some date in that interval, but they will be not so fast and all your future queries should use that dates.

Comment: Essentially youre talking about building an audit log for this particular element. I would consider what much audit logging you really need (meaning that if you have tons of audit requirements maybe building a process for change data capture). This is a more advanced concept and best practice standards may change from RDBMS to RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the complete situation. Typically it's simpler and more efficient to keep all associations in a single associative table. Like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE works_with (
  student_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES students
, tutor_id   int NOT NULL REFERENCES tutors
, start_date date NOT NULL
, end_date   date
, termination_reason text
, PRIMARY KEY (student_id, tutor_id, start_date)
, CONSTRAINT end_not_before_start
     CHECK (end_date >= start_date)
, CONSTRAINT
     CHECK (end_date IS NOT NULL OR termination_reason IS NULL)
, CONSTRAINT no_overlapping_date_range
     EXCLUDE USING gist (student_id with =, tutor_id with =, daterange(start_date, end_date) WITH &&)
);
```

The PK includes `start_date` now, as the same student & tutor might work together repeatedly over time. Since the exclusion constraint (see below) prevents overlapping entries anyway, you might as well use an additional surrogate PK column (like a `serial` or `IDENTITY` column) as well. May be more efficient.

The check constraint `end_not_before_start` forbids end before start (while still allowing `end_date IS NULL`.

The check constraint `termination_reason_only_if_terminated` only allows a value in termination_reason where the association has been terminated.

The exclusion constraint `no_overlapping_date_range` disallows overlapping date ranges per student-tutor combination. (You may or may not want that.)
Requires the [additional module `btree_gist`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html). Install once per database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;  -- once per db
```

See:

- [Store the day of the week and time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895140/store-the-day-of-the-week-and-time/19897592#19897592)
- [Postgres constraint for unique datetime range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735955/postgres-constraint-for-unique-datetime-range/26736759#26736759)
- [Preventing adjacent/overlapping entries with EXCLUDE in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504727/preventing-adjacent-overlapping-entries-with-exclude-in-postgresql/19505869#19505869)