# ERROR: could not create exclusion constraint

Tags: postgresql, database-design, overlap, exclusion-constraint, range-types

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE attendances
(
    id_attendance serial PRIMARY KEY,
    id_user integer NOT NULL 
         REFERENCES users (user_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    entry_date timestamp with time zone DEFAULT NULL,
    departure_date timestamp with time zone DEFAULT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT current_timestamp
);
```

I want to add an exclusion constraint avoiding attendance to overlap (There can be multiple rows for the same day, but time ranges cannot overlap).

So I wrote this code to add the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE attendances 
   ADD CONSTRAINT check_attendance_overlaps
   EXCLUDE USING GIST (box(
      point(
        extract(epoch from entry_date at time zone 'UTC'),
        id_user
      ),
      point(
         extract(epoch from departure_date at time zone 'UTC') - 0.5,
         id_user + 0.5
      )
  )
WITH && );
```

But when I tried to run it on the database I got this error:

> Error: could not create exclusion constraint "check_attendance_overlaps"

[image]

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help] [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Comment: Looks like you already have conflicting rows.

Answer (score 2):

To exclude overlapping time ranges per user, work with a multicolumn constraint on `id_user` and a `timestamptz` range ([`tstzrange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN)).

You need the additional module [`btree_gist`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html) once per database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist;
```

Then:

```sql
ALTER TABLE attendances ADD CONSTRAINT check_attendance_overlaps
EXCLUDE USING gist (id_user WITH =
                  , tstzrange(entry_date, departure_date) WITH &&)
```

See:

- [Store the day of the week and time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895140/store-the-day-of-the-week-and-time/19897592#19897592)
- [Postgres constraint for unique datetime range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735955/postgres-constraint-for-unique-datetime-range/26736759#26736759)

Or maybe `spgist` instead of `gist`. Might be faster. See:

- [Perform this hours of operation query in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108477/perform-this-hours-of-operation-query-in-postgresql/22111524#22111524)

Of course, there cannot be overlapping rows in the table, or adding the constraint will fail with a similar error message.