# Transform timestamp to local time for a given timezone during 'COPY .. TO ..'

Tags: postgresql, types, timezone, timestamp

I have a log table in a PostgreSQL database with an `event` column of type `timestamp without time zone`.

Now I have a bash script, which creates a CSV file from the log database:

```
...
psql .. -c "COPY (SELECT event, ... FROM logtable order by event desc) TO STDOUT WITH CSV" logdb > log.csv
...
```

This is executed on the cloud server on which the DB is hosted and therefore, the timestamp strings in log.csv are in local time of the timezone of the server.

However, I like to have the timestamp strings to represent the time of my own time zone. So I shall be able to let psql transform the timestamp -> string to a given timezone. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should use **`timestamptz`** instead of `timestamp` whenever working with multiple times zones. Would avoid the problem completely.

Details:

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

You *can* use the `AT TIME ZONE` construct like [@NuLo suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32353687/939860), it *may* even work, but not exactly as described.

`AT TIME ZONE` converts the type `timestamp` (`timestamp without time zone`) to `timestamptz` (`timestamp with time zone`) and vice versa. The ***text representation*** of a `timestamptz` value depends on the *current setting* of the time zone in the session in which you run the command. These two `timestamptz` *values* are 100 % identical (denote the same point in time):

```
'2015-09-02 15:55:00+02'::timestamptz
'2015-09-02 14:55:00+01'::timestamptz
```

But the text representation is *not*. The display is for different time zones. If you take this string literal and feed it to a `timestamp` type, the time zone part is just *ignored* and you end up with *different* values. Hence, if you run your `COPY` statement in a session with the same time zone setting as your original `timestamp` values are for, the suggested operation *happens* to work.

The clean way, however, is to produce correct `timestamp` values to begin with by applying `AT TIME ZONE` ***twice***:

```
SELECT event AT TIME ZONE 'my_target_tz' AT TIME ZONE 'my_source_tz', ...
FROM   logtable
ORDER  BY event desc;
```

`'my_target_tz'` is "your own time zone" and `'my_source_tz'` the time zone of the of the cloud server in the example. To make sure that DST is respected use **time zone names**, not time zone abbreviations. [The documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES)

> A time zone abbreviation, for example `PST`. Such a specification merely
>   defines a particular offset from UTC, in contrast to full time zone names
>   which can imply a set of daylight savings transition-date rules as well.

Related:

- [Accounting for DST in Postgres, when selecting scheduled items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239534/accounting-for-dst-in-postgres-when-selecting-scheduled-items/13243029#13243029)
- [Time zone names with identical properties yield different result when applied to timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042506/time-zone-names-with-identical-properties-yield-different-result-when-applied-to)

Or, much better yet, use `timestamptz` everywhere and it works correctly automatically.

Comment: Thank you Erwin. Using AT TIME ZONE twice with correct time zone names (the source is EDT, the target is Europe/Zurich) works like a charm - even with daylight time saving rule applied. Perfect!

Comment: @badera: I added a bit about time zone names, abbreviations and DST.