# CASE expression to help altering data type text to boolean

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, alter-table

I have a column called `still_available` with the values of *'Removed'* and *'Still_available'*. The original table looks like this:

[image: original table]

Since there are only two values I want to cast it to `boolean` e.g 'Removed' => False and 'Still_available' => True. So I did this:

```
dim_products_set_still_available_to_bool = f"""
UPDATE public.dim_products
SET still_available = 
                CASE
                    WHEN still_available = 'Removed' THEN {False}
                    ELSE {True}
                END;
"""
```

On row 4 it sets the value to `true`. I was expecting the rows to be set properly to the new values so I can cast the column datatype to `boolean`.

---

I'm not sure why but once I copied the actual string from the database it seems to work completely with:

```
dim_products_set_still_available_to_bool = f"""
UPDATE public.dim_products
SET still_available = 
                CASE
                    WHEN still_available = 'Removed' THEN {False}
                    WHEN still_available = 'Still_avaliable' THEN {True}
                END;
"""
```

Comment: Please remember to post table definition and sample data as formatted *text*, never as image. We can't copy/paste from an image.

Comment: Yeah that's no problem, it was just a dataframe that i uploaded to the table after cleaning and reading from a pdf, this is all through python so thought explanation, i will remember for the future to have some sample data

Comment: BTW, I see a column named "uuid" type `text`. Should probably be type `uuid`. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/115271/3684

Comment: Yeah thats all done altered my column types after all of this just couldn't alter the columns all at once since i needed to that column to boolean

Answer (score 1):

> I was expecting the rows to be set properly to the new values so I can cast the column datatype to boolean

You should really just `ALTER` the column type. Don't run a separate `UPDATE` first, that would double the cost. Do the conversion in a `USING` clause:

```sql
ALTER TABLE public.dim_products
ALTER COLUMN still_available TYPE boolean USING 
                CASE still_available
                    WHEN 'Removed' THEN false
                    WHEN 'Still_avaliable' THEN true
                    -- ELSE null  -- default
                END;
```

This rewrites the table in pristine condition and takes an exclusive lock for the duration.

Related:

- [Will changing column from timestamp to timestamptz lock the table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32480700/will-changing-column-from-timestamp-to-timestamptz-lock-the-table/32481513#32481513)
- [ALTER timestamptz column to timestamp without "converting" data?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/322907/3684)

Comment: This i never knew, you learn a lot by asking questions, yeah theres a few times where i'm doing exactly the same as outlined above, I will edit the question above to include what i mean so you can have a look

Comment: I just noticed my edit will be hella long lol so i'll just leave it for now but thank you so much furthermore can i ask you another question some of the postgressql statements i am send as a functional string however, from what i read that is prone to sql injection since i'd like to use this as part of my resume what would be the best way to avoid this? i did hear something about parametized sql statements but i'm essentially clueless tbh

Comment: @SwingingTreebranch: Please ask your new question as question. Comments are not the place. Maybe some existing Q/A help already: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18386034/939860 or https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159534/3684 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/17355733/939860

Comment: Perfect exactly answers my question will have to read that throughly first and yeah its because i cannot post a question currently

Comment: So do you have your answer here?