# SQL 'AT TIME ZONE', query wide and with a 'SELECT' all columns (tablename.*) expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone, timestamp

I use `timestamp(3) with time zone` in my database for the tables when one is necessary, this is almost any case in my situation.

I need to select all columns of a table possibly in a much more complex query than the following.

My question is how to get the timestamps (with time zone) at the desired time zone with SQL `at time zone '<TIMEZONE>'` for a select expression like `q.*` one of which is the timestamp (with time zone) column.
I might have subqueries with the same situation.
Is there an expression to achieve this for query wide?

```
SELECT
    q.*, -- created_at timestamp (with time zone) is already in here
    q.created_at AT TIME ZONE 'EET', --instead of this redundant column selection
    u.name AS author,
    u.reputation,
    CASE WHEN count(t.*)=0 THEN '[]' ELSE json_agg(t.*) END as tags
FROM posts q

-- authors
JOIN users u
ON q.author_id = u.id

-- tags
left join post_has_tag p_h_t
on q.id = p_h_t.post_id
left join tags t
on p_h_t.tag_id = t.id

WHERE q.post_type = 'question'
group by q.id, u.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your columns are of type `timestamp`, then using `AT TIME ZONE` is the correct way to convert them to a specific time zone.

However, don't use `EET`.  Use a specific locality-based time zone [from this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), such as `Europe/Bucharest` - or whatever is applicable for you.

Alternatively, if your columns are of type `timestamp with time zone`, then you can set the session's time zone and postgres will do the conversion for you:

```
SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Bucharest'
```

You should read up on [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) to understand the difference of these two timestamp types.

Comment: By 'session' do you mean the current transaction, or the query, as it is a transaction implicitly, too?

Comment: See [these docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html).  Basically, `SESSION` is the default, and is scoped for the entire connection to the db.  `LOCAL` is for the current transaction.

Comment: Currently I use the `SET TIME ZONE` construct with my query in the question and similar ones. However, the timestamps inside the `post` table ,the first table -the leftest in joins is not considered in the set time zone. The ones in `tags` table were output in specified time one by the clause at the beginnig. What can be the reason for this?

Comment: `timestamp` and `timestamptz` are two different types.  The session/local time zone setting only affects `timestamptz`  (aka "timestamp with time zone")

Comment: all the fields related to times and dates are my `timestamp(3) with time zone` values, both in `posts` table and `tags` table.

Comment: Everything is ok in my *pgAdmin3 SQL Editor*. When I write the query in my question with `set local time zone 'Europe/Oslo'` I get bot the `posts` and `tags` table `created_at` fields correct with `+2` offset in the output. However, when I put it in a route function in my *Nodejs* *express.js* server with *pg-promise* as the connection lib, I only get the `tags` table `created_at` field correct with the time in Oslo with timezone appended as expected, I get `created_at` field of the `posts` table in UTC as not expected. Does not the set local directive bind all the query?

Comment: Sorry, you're asking things I'm not familiar with.  Perhaps others can help.  Maybe edit your question or ask a new one?

Comment: Sorry. Yiu are right, maybe I should ask it as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic setting to convert all columns of data type `timestamptz` to `timestamp`. But you can set the desired target time zone (temporarily) to adjust the ***display*** (the **text representation**) of the `timestamptz` value:

```
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL timezone = 'EET';
SELECT q.*, -- including created_at timestamp as original timestamptz type
     , u.name AS author,
     , ...

 -- do something with your data

COMMIT;  -- or ROLLBACK; doesn't matter for just SELECT
```

This is *not* the same as applying the `AT TIME ZONE` construct, which actually converts `timestamp` to `timestamptz` and vice versa. Details:

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170?noredirect=1#comment65763718_9576170)

Effects of `SET LOCAL` last till the end of the transaction.

And (like [@Matt already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39213023/939860)) it's generally (even if a bit more expensive) preferable to use actual time zone names over time zone abbreviations. Time zone *names* take DST and other peculiarities of the time zone into account:

```
SET LOCAL timezone = 'Europe/Istanbul';
```

- [Time zone names with identical properties yield different result when applied to timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042506/time-zone-names-with-identical-properties-yield-different-result-when-applied-to)

#### Demo

```
BEGIN;
SET timezone = 'Europe/Istanbul';
SELECT now();

now
-----------------------------
2016-08-29 22:39:09.275647+03

SET timezone = 'UTC';
SELECT now();

now
-----------------------------
2016-08-29 19:39:09.275647+00

COMMIT;
```

Comment: I am little bit more confused now. I use `timestamp with time zone` in all my tables.I need to show different time zone users the correct representation of time according to their time zones.While writing I do not do any special things just insert or use `CREATE_TIMESTAMP`. My db can be in a different time zone than the GMT. However, while I read I have planned to read with `at time zone` clause, with the full time zone names I will do it, so that the users see the times in their time zones. But only problem I see is with the syntax of the `at time zone` it cannot apply to a filed inside `p.*`

Comment: I have come to those conclusions and application desicions regarding timestamp usage after reading the mentioned SO question and some other, in which you @Erwin was involved, many thanks . Am I missing something?

Comment: How does Postgres know about "their timezone"? If they query with the respective time zone set in the session, the display is adjusted *automatically*.

Comment: I will get their timezone from the request, somehow. Any way I need to take it from the user to query Postgres correctly, whether with setting the session timezone, or with `at time zone`, I may be wrong with the idea of usage of this second SQL construct with `timestamp with timezone`

Comment: I get a `query result with 5 rows discarded.
Query returned successfully with no result in 20 msec.
` message in the pgAdmin3 SQL Editor.
When I omit the begin and commit it gives rows, 5 rows,  from the table, also the time zone set above is applied
What is the reason?

Comment: By the way, from node.js with `pg-promise` I can get the `p.created_at` from the `posts` table as `"created_at":"2016-08-30T15:14:03.869Z"` which is in `GMT`, but another `timestamptz` type column from the `tags` table created with the same post at the same time is`"created_at":"2016-08-30T17:14:03.869+02:00"` that is presented accordingly, according to the set time zone with `SET LOCAL TIME ZONE 'Europe/Oslo';`. Note they are in the same query, even same transaction, the second one is just in the join parts following.

Comment: What is the reason for that? A bug in `pg-promise`?

Comment: @Işık: `5 rows discarded`: Execute each command of the demo separately to see results, not the whole demo at once. `"2016-08-30T15:14:03.869Z"` is a `timestamp` literal (no offset), while `"2016-08-30T17:14:03.869+02:00"` is a timestamptz literal (with offset). Not sure what's going on there.